# value changing in object that kept in localstorage

Tags: object, local-storage

I have an object in localStore

```
products = { apples: 2, tomatoes: 3, potatoes: 1}
```

How to change tomatoes into 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What did you try? If you already have that in localStorage, you must have serialized it into JSON first. You didn't say as much in your post, but as you can only store strings you must have. So I assume you did this to get the value as data:

```
let products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
```

At this point, products is a regular old JavaScript object, so you could do:

```
products.tomatoes = 5;
```

To persist it back, you convert it back into JSON and use `setItem`.

```
localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(products));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This what I really need.